# Variable was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm trying to write a simple loop that iterates over the lines of a datafile, containing path to specific files, and checking if they exist, this is the code i have so far:

```
:: read file line by line

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%DATAFILEPATH%) do (
 IF EXISTS %%a (
   echo FILE %a EXISTS
)
)
pause
```

And i get the following error message, but i dont understand why:

```
 %a was unexpected at this time.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Command line `%a` Batch file : `%%a`. Also, `if exist`

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two main problems, the first being a plural **`EXISTS`** and the second a singular **`%a`** try it like this:

```bat
REM read file line by line

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%a IN (%DATAFILEPATH%) DO (
   IF EXIST "%%~a" ECHO FILE %%a EXISTS
)

PAUSE
```

If the location identified from **`%DATAFILEPATH%`** was a folder/directory then you'd change the **`IF`** line to **`IF EXIST "%%~a\" ECHO FOLDER %%a EXISTS`**